# Umbraco 7 Custom Membership Provider use both Umbraco Users and external Members

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, membership, user-roles

how can i use in `Umbraco 7` the internal Users and roles  who use the `BackOffice` and my custom users and roles (which comes from an external `SQL database`.
i want log in umbraco backoffice with the umbraco users as it is and with seperate Login want use external users. i have already changed the web.config

`<add name="mynewMembershipProvider" type="mynewMembershipProvider, mynew" 
  <add name="mynewrovider" type="mynewrsRoleProvider"/>`

when i go now to my custom Login i can Login my custom user . but when i try

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

or

`User.IsInRole("xyz")`
umbraco is always looking at the umbraco roles.

what did i have done wrong
best regards Michael

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you are leaving CMS and back office *Users* as-is, and you want to allow *Member* login on the public facing side of your site with a custom provider?

Did you set the default provider to your new membership provider?

```
<membership defaultProvider="mynewMembershipProvider">
...
</membership>
```

The default provider in the membership section should always point to the provider being used for public-facing *Members* - the backoffice interally asks for the `UsersMembershipProvider` every time it needs to authenticate, so changing the default will not affect it at all.

It is also possible depending on your set up (I haven't tried this) that if you did not include a `<clear/>` directive then the original Umbraco member provider is causing problems.

Here is a full working `<membership>` section using a custom BCrypt hashing provider from an Umbraco 7 install of mine:

```
<membership defaultProvider="BCryptMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add 
            name="BCryptMembershipProvider" 
            type="cFront.Web.Security.BCryptMembershipProvider" 
            connectionStringName="umbracoDbDSN" 
            requiresUniqueEmail="0"
        />
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="BCryptRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="BCryptRoleProvider" type="cFront.Web.Security.BCryptRoleProvider" 
            connectionStringName="umbracoDbDSN" 
            availableRoles="SuperUser,Administrator,Manager,User"
        />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: I found that simply invoking the login via the web.config setting deny users ="?" routes both Members and Users to the same login form; so the standard Umbraco login no longer appears. Also, its a bit confusing when the Membership provider has methods like ValidateUser.